# imacros set variable to another variables value

Tags: javascript, imacros

Im running a simple imacro to automatically add sub-domain dns records using the front end of 123reg. However my naming convention I need to use is causing some issues.

I have two domains im mapping x.x.x.1   - x.x.x.128 on domain1.com
                              x.x.x.129 - x.x.x.254 on domain2.com

Here is the code I used to map domain1.com's addresses

```
TAB T=1
SET !LOOP 1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:advanced_DNS ATTR=NAME:hostname CONTENT=mx{{!LOOP}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:advanced_DNS ATTR=NAME:data_A CONTENT=x.x.x.{{!LOOP}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:save_dns_entries
WAIT SECONDS=2
```

Ideally, Ive been trying to add a variable !VAR0 and do some simple maths, ie.

```
!VAR0 !LOOP
ADD !VAR0 -128
TAB T=1
SET !LOOP 1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:advanced_DNS ATTR=NAME:hostname CONTENT=mx{{!VAR0}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:advanced_DNS ATTR=NAME:data_A CONTENT=x.x.x.{{!LOOP}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:save_dns_entries
WAIT SECONDS=2
```

This format simply adds "!LOOP" to !VAR0...is there a way to set one variables value as another's value in imacros? Im aware that its mathmatical functionality is very limited...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem with a bit of better thinking! Surround a variable or loop (!VAR0 or !LOOP) with {{}} i.e. {{!LOOP}} will give the value of that variable.

To set the value of a variable then perform math on it:

```
!VAR0 {{!LOOP}} 
!VAR0 - 128
```

The following is the solution to my above example which under 123reg.com's advanced DNS entry, will allow very quick and automatic adding of subdomains in the format mx0.domain.com where '0' is a the range of numbers, and x.x.x. is the first 3 points of an IP address; useful if you are mapping a range of IP's to subdomains on a server's DNS.

```
TAB T=1
SET !LOOP 129
SET !VAR0 {{!LOOP}}
ADD !VAR0 -128
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:advanced_DNS ATTR=NAME:hostname CONTENT=mx{{!VAR0}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:advanced_DNS ATTR=NAME:data_A CONTENT=x.x.x.{{!LOOP}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:save_dns_entries
WAIT SECONDS=2
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use iMacros scripting interface. And commands iimSet and iimPlay.